# Is the akaike information criterion (AIC) unit-dependent?

Tags: statistics, modeling

One formula for AIC is:

AIC = 2k + n*Log(RSS/n)

Intuitively, if you add a parameter to your model, your AIC will decrease (and hence you should keep the parameter), if the increase in the 2k term due to the new parameter is offset by the decrease in the n*Log(RSS/n) term due to the decreased residual sum of squares. But isn't this RSS value unit-specific? So if I'm modeling money, and my units are in millions of dollars, the change in RSS with adding a parameter might be very small, and won't offset the increase in the 2k term. Conversely, if my units are pennies, the change in RSS would be very large, and could greatly offset the increase in the 2k term. This arbitrary change in units would lead to a change in my decision whether to keep the extra parameter.

So: does the RSS have to be in standardized units for AIC to be a useful criterion? I don't see how it could be otherwise.

Comment: AIC is a measure for model comparison. Only differences in AIC between at least 2 models are meaningful. So, I'm inclined to say it doesn't matter.

Comment: What I'm saying is precisely that the difference in AIC between two models could depend on your choice of units: if you have model A and model B, where model B only differs by the addition of another model parameter, then by the logic in the original post the change in AIC will depend on your choice of units, since it will determine whether the residual sum of squares term trumps the 2k term or not.

Comment: Are you sure that your premise about RSS is correct? Your AIC formula arises in the context of least squares regression. IIRC, if you change the unit of one independent variable from dollars to cent (leaving all other units unchanged), the new least squares parameter estimator for that variable divides by 100 and RSS doesn't change (I may be wrong though - it's been a while for me). More generally, how can the *maximum* of the data's likelihood function be influenced by the multiplication with a constant?

Comment: What you say is true for the IVs, but not for the DV as far as I can see. If your DV is in units of dollars then you might have a residual of 1, but if it's in cents it'd be a residual of 100. I agree, in the maximum likelihood formulation for AIC it makes no sense that it would depend on the units, but in the version of AIC that uses RSS it seems like the units of the DV must necessarily make a difference (unless standardizing your residuals or something).

Comment: Even when (I'm too lazy to think through it right now), if you change the units of the DV you must obviously do it for *both* models, A and B. Again, I think it wouldn't affect the AIC difference.

Comment: Even if you change it for both models, the absolute difference in RSS between the two will be bigger if you use smaller units, which means it could change whether or not the reduction in the RSS term between the simpler and more complex model exceeds the increase in the 2k term or not. So it could influence whether or not you add an additional parameter to the model.

Comment: Yes. As long as the response variable of the models being compared has the same unit, using RSS in the AIC formula results in a valid comparison. It seems possible that, using another unit, the ordering of A and B may change. I believe you'd have to normalize the response variable or use the exact log-likelihood maximum value to avoid that. In any case, these kind of questions belong to https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think so (partially rowing back from what I said in my earlier comment). For the simplest possible case (least squares regression for y = *a*x + *b*), from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares#Relation_with_Pearson's_product-moment_correlation), RSS = S<sub>yy</sub> - *a* x S<sub>xy</sub>.

From their definitions given in that article, both *a* and S<sub>xy</sub> grow by a factor of *100* and S<sub>yy</sub> grows by a factor of *100<sup>2</sup>* if you change the unit for *y* from dollars to cents. So, after rescaling, the new RSS for that model will be *100<sup>2</sup>* times the the old one. I'm quite sure that the same result holds for models with *k <> 2* parameters.

Hence nothing changes for the AIC difference where the key part is *log(RSS<sub>B</sub>/RSS<sub>A</sub>)*. After rescaling both RSS will have grown by the same factor and you'll get the exact same AIC difference between model A and B as before.

**Edit:**

I've just found this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486/negative-values-for-aicc-corrected-akaike-information-criterion#comment10669_720):

> "It is correct that the choice of units introduces a multiplicative
>   constant into the likelihood. Thence the *log* likelihood has an
>   *additive* constant which contributes (after doubling) to the AIC. The difference of AICs is unchanged."

Note that this comment even talks about the *general* case where the exact log-likelihood is used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and I felt like the existing answer above could have been clearer and more direct.  Hopefully the following clarifies it a bit for others as well.

When using the AIC to compare models, it is the difference that is of interest.  The portion in question here is the n*log(RSS/n).  When we compare this for two different models, we will get:
n1*log(RSS1/n1) + 2k1 - n2*log(RSS2/n2) - 2k2

From our logarithmic identities, we know that log(a) - log(b) = log(a/b).  AIC1 - AIC2 therefore simplifies to:

2k1 - 2k2 + log(RSS1*n2/(RSS2*n1))

If we add a gain factor G to represent a change in units, that difference becomes:

2k1 - 2k2 + log(G*RSS1*n2/(G*RSS2*n1)) = 2k1 - 2k2 + log(RSS1*n2/(RSS2*n1))

As you can see, we are left with the same AIC difference, regardless of which units we choose.